# app.UseAuthentication(); not working with Jwt token C# .Net Core 3.1 in (MVC web application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, jwt

I am trying to apply JWT Authorization in web application. Every time my application returns 401(Un-authorized), even after passing Authorize header attribute with valid bearer token.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddDbContextPool<SchoolCMS.Service.Context.SchoolCMSContext>(options
     => options.UseMySQL(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]));
     services.AddControllersWithViews();
     services.AddControllers()
     .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                   {
                       options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                       options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                   });
    
     services.AddSession(options => {
             options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);

      });
      services.AddSignalR();
      services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
      //Provide a secret key to Encrypt and Decrypt the Token
            var SecretKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769- 
                            0921-kfirox29zoxv");
            //Configure JWT Token Authentication - JRozario
            services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(token =>
            {
                token.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                token.SaveToken = true;
                token.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(SecretKey),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    //Usually this is your application base URL - JRozario
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:45092/",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    //Here we are creating and using JWT within the same application. In this case base URL is fine
                    //If the JWT is created using a web service then this could be the consumer URL
                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:45092/",
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
            
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseSession();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var JWToken = context.Session.GetString("JWToken");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JWToken))
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWToken);
                }
                await next();
            });
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            //app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/schoolapp-web"));//When merging code to master branch comment this line
            var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            SessionUtility.Configure(httpContextAccessor);

           
         
            app.ApplicationServices.GetService<AssignDailyTaskService>();
            
            
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/NotificationHub", options =>
                {
                    options.Transports =
                        HttpTransportType.WebSockets |
                        HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
                });
            });
        }
```

**Account Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(Login model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        UserModel user = await _userService.ValidateUser(model);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.emailverify)
            {
                if (user.IsApprove)
                {
                    if (user.IsLock)
                    {
                        @ViewBag.Message = "Your account has locked. Please contact 
                        administrator.";
                        return View(model);
                    }
                    else if (user.ApplicationStartDate == null)
                    {
                        CustomResponseModel response = await 
                       _applicantService.LockUnlockApplicant(user.PKUserID);
                        if (response.IsSuccess)
                        {
                            user.ApplicationStartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
                            user.ApplicationEndDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(45);
                        }
                    }
                    var jwtSettings = _configuration.GetSection("JwtAuthorizationSettings");
                    var token = _tokenGenerator.GenerateJwtToken(
                           jwtSettings["SecretKey"],
                           jwtSettings["Issuer"],
                           jwtSettings["Audience"],
                           new List<Claim>
                           {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Convert.ToString(user.FirstName)),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Convert.ToString(user.FirstName)),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Convert.ToString(user.EmailID)),
                        new Claim("UserId", Convert.ToString(user.PKUserID)),
                           },
                           Convert.ToInt32(jwtSettings["ExpirationTimeInMinute"]));


                    SessionUtility.SetObject("JWToken", token);
                    SessionUtility.SetObject("CurrentUser", user);
                   
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                }
              }
           }
                
        }
          return View(model);
}
```

**Generate Jwt Token**

```
public string GenerateJwtToken(string secretKey, string issuer, string audience, IList<Claim> claims, 
                                   int expirationTimeInMinute)
            {
                    //Provide the security key which was given in the JWToken configuration in Startup.cs
                    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921- 
                          kfirox29zoxv");
                    //Generate Token for user - JRozario
                    var JWToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "http://localhost:45092/",
                    audience: "http://localhost:45092/",
                    claims: claims,
                    notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
                    expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).DateTime,
                    //Using HS256 Algorithm to encrypt Token - JRozario
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), 
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                );
                    var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWToken);
                    return token;
            }
```

I am still getting User.Identity.Claims count 0. I don't know where I am doing the mistake. Please suggest me the valid solution.

I took refernce from this Url :- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5247609/ASP-NET-CORE-Token-Authentication-and-Authorizat-2

This code project is working, but unfortunately not working on my web application.

Thanks in advance!!